# Best way to show HTML content in Mail.Body in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

Any body having any idea about this, how can I do this??

Thanks

Comment: What format are the files.  Are they HTML, msg ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control. The `NavigateToString` allows you to display a `string`. However be aware of the security implications, because the mail could execute malicious scripts, etc.